# how to authenticated google service account to call youtube API to generate token in java

Tags: java, youtube

I m developing web application for getting particular youtube video detail.for this i did the code like call authorization process using google service account.i thought authentication is done and its not generating the token.while i run my code it getting error like "INVALID_GRANT".Please help me to resolve this.

```
        here my sample code is as:

    String clientId = "Something.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
                List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
                scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");
                final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
                final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(clientId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
                .build();
                System.out.println("credential............."+credential);
                YouTube youtube=new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("test").build();
                System.out.println("Responce.............."+youtube);
                com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities act=youtube.activities();
                com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities.List list=act.list("");
                list.execute();
                System.out.println("list Details...................."+list);

    here i passes Youtube Api to retrieving the list.

    error :

    Exceptioncom.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "error" : "invalid_grant"
    }

    i m waiting for all of ur response to resolve this problem..Thanks all once again to spend time with my pro
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with your method of authentication but there are two things:

1. in `.setServiceAccountId(clientId)` you use **clientId** as the argument, but in the documentary it is stated that it is typically an **e-mail address**:

> Builder com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.Builder.setServiceAccountId(String serviceAccountId)
>
> @Beta
>
> Beta
>
> Sets the service account ID (typically an e-mail address) or null for none.

2. in `.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))` you specify a file called **key.p12** which isn't a file

Sorry if your code from above isn't the real code and just for demonstrating purpose.

---

If those two things don't help, you could try this method (it works for me):

```
        // FileDataStoreFactory is used to create new credentials and 
        // simultaneously loads previously generated credentials from a file
        // Specify a location where the file should be stored via DIRECTORY
        // The file is automatically generated and encrypted
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(DIRECTORY));

        // Create the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. This is needed to get the user (you?)
        // approval (you need that so you can access data). getClientSecrets() returns a
        // GoogleClientSecrets. If you want to, I can provide some code :)
        // Here you also specify your scopes
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getClientSecrets(), Arrays.asList(scope))
            .setCredentialDataStore(StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(fileDataStoreFactory)).build();

        // With the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow you can create a Credential
        Credential cred = flow.loadCredential("user");

        // Check if the cred is null or expired (credentials last about an hour I think)
        if(cred == null || (cred.getExpiresInSeconds() < 100 && !cred.refreshToken())){
            // If it is expired, you need to refresh it via UserAuthorization, again, if you
            // want to I can provide an example code
            GoogleTokenResponse resp = getUserAuthorization(flow);
            if(resp == null){
                return null;
            }
            cred = flow.createAndStoreCredential(resp, "user");
        }
```

In your code you can use the Credential exactly like the GoogleCredential:

```
            System.out.println("credential............."+ cred);
            YouTube youtube=new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, cred).setApplicationName("test").build();
            System.out.println("Responce.............."+youtube);
            com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities act=youtube.activities();
            com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities.List list=act.list("");
            list.execute();
            System.out.println("list Details...................."+list);
```

I hope this helps :)

---

For this I followed this tutorial: [Google's Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=de)

For server-side applications: [Google's Tutorial about server-side applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=de#server-side-apps)

And web-applications using JavaScript: [Google's Tutorial about web-applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=de#client-side-apps)

Comment: Thanks Crphrags,it working fine now,able to get all details from youtube API Call.

Comment: hi Cyphrags,i have one more small query,wt ever ur provided smaple code is to store the access token by using server side webapplication?

Comment: I use this code to store the authentification key on clients. This might also work on server (If you want to make like an upload-server for youtube videos or so, where you would upload your files to the server which then uploads them to youtube). Where whould you need to store the data? Or what do you want to make? :)

Comment: i would like to retrieve youtube video ids based upon assets id..till now i did authentication by using service account,by using service account able to generate token and i passed it through get url,but i got 404 (not found error)

Comment: So your application is running on a local client and not on a server?

Comment: i m using CMS account details to retrieve it.while this will be working in client location